# MySQL statement not working properly

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which there is an `if` statement, where `foto_id` is an `integer` and `datums` is of `date` type:

```
if((select count(*) from (select pv.Datums, pv.Fotografs from pieteikumi_view pv 
    where pv.Fotografs=foto_id and pv.Datums=datums)as tab) = 0) then
    select 3;
else
    select -2;
```

When I tested it outside procedure with exact same values, as when calling procedure like this:

```
select count(*) from (select pv.Datums, pv.Fotografs from pieteikumi_view pv
    where pv.Fotografs='9' and pv.Datums='2016-01-01')as tab;
```

I get the desired result, however inside procedure the `if` statement returns `true` even when this `select` statement returns row count.
I'd be glad for any pointers to what am I doing wrong...

P.S. Is this information enough, or do I need to provide complete procedure and table information?

Comment: Use instead SELECT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is how if statement looks in mySql:

```
IF Boolean_expression 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } 
[ ELSE 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

If you write it this way everything should be good. Besides, you can always use CASE WHEN, it'll be something like that:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
((select count(*) from (select pv.Datums, pv.Fotografs from pieteikumi_view pv where pv.Fotografs=foto_id and pv.Datums=datums)as tab) = 0) 
THEN 3 
ELSE -2 
END;
```

Comment: I just tried writing exactly as you provided the if statement syntax, but MySQL Workbench was throwing errors at me left and right.. I could only write
    `if expression then`
        `statement;`
    `else`
        `statement;`
    `end if;`

Comment: As well as, I just can't figure out how to rewrite using `select case` when I have a couple nested `if` statements and `insert into` inside those.